# How to change width of AppBar() in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to reuse mobile app code for flutter web. I already coded with AppBar() and body widgets in scaffold in all screens. Now i am taking 400 width and center for web, it is good except appbar.

```
        Scaffold(
        appBar: this.getAppBarWidget(),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: kIsWeb ? 400.0 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: this.getBodyWidget(),
          ),
        ))
```

Above code is perfectly working for all screens of mobile and web except appbar in web.

How do i change width of appbar to fit width 400 ?

If i use Size.fromWidth(400) getting error.

Below code is working for mobile and web.

```
   Scaffold(
    body: Center(
  child: Container(
    width: kIsWeb ? 400.0 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        this.getCustomAppbarWidget(),
        this.getBodyWidget(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
))
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The size this widget would prefer if it were otherwise unconstrained.
> In many cases it's only necessary to define one preferred dimension. For example the [Scaffold] only depends on its app bar's preferred height. In that case implementations of this method can just return new Size.fromHeight(myAppBarHeight).

But we can provide customAppBar like

```dart
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.pink,
        // we can set width here with conditions
        width: 200,
        height: kToolbarHeight,
        child: Text("MY AppBar"),
      ),
    );
  }

  ///width doesnt matter
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(200, kToolbarHeight);
}
```

and use

```
Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: ......
```

if it cover the 1st item of body, and in this case use  `SizedBox(height: kToolbarHeight)` to handle the situation if needed.
**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As i know, width did not allow in AppBar. Only height is allowed in AppBar

`toolbarHeight: 60,`

But if you want to apply manually width in your AppBar you can wrap your AppBar in Padding component

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: kIsWeb? 400 : double.maxFinite,
            child: AppBar(
              title: Text('hello'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: HomePageOne()), // this expanded is you page body
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. I have checked with your answer also. It is working fine.  As @Yeasin Sheikh suggested, i can take separate class for appbar, then i can easily reuse it.