# CircleAvatar() size is not changing inside the appBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

So am trying to display circular user image in the home page of an application the image position is at the top left of the screen, after searching and trying i managed to use this approach:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
    child: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 10,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/DefaultImage.png'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

the image is displayed fine but i want to increase the size of it and "radius" is not working at all, i tried to wrap the avatar with container to add some margins but also didn't work.

my questions are :

1- how to increase the size of `CircleAvatar()` inside an `AppBar()`.

2- is `CircleAvatar()` the right choice for user profile image especially if this image was retrieved from firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`leading` is controlled by `leadingWidth` and `toolbarHeight`. You can increase the size to have more space.

```dart
child: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
    elevation: 0,
    toolbarHeight: 100, //this
    leadingWidth: 100, //this
    leading: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 60,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Glad to help. Also, I was thinking not to use appBar here.  Going for Row. Also while we are already using `PreferredSize`, We can have more control over AppBar like creating new widget [implementing PreferredSizeWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69056129/10157127)