# How to resize a flutter table to take the whole available space?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-appbar

I have a Flutter table that is currently being rendered in the Appbar title as follows:

[image]

My question is how to make the table take the maximum width and height of the AppBar?

The codes for defining the table in the Appbar is as follows:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(),
          children: [
            TableRow(
              children: <Widget>[
                TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: Center(child: Text("GPS"),),
                ),
                TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: Center(child: Text("GPS"),),
                ),
                TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: Center(child: Text("GPS"),),
                ),
                TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: Center(child: Text("GPS"),),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ))
```

Below is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, provide height on `TableCell`,

```dart
TableCell(
  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
  child: Container(
    height: kToolbarHeight,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text("GPS"),
  ),
),
```

**Option 1**

You can use `leadingWidth: 0,titleSpacing: 0,` on AppBar.

```dart
AppBar(
  leadingWidth: 0,
  titleSpacing: 0,
  title: myTable(),
),
```

Option 1 rendering:

[image]

**Option 2**

Also I think you will like using `PreferredSize` and customize the way you like

```dart
appBar: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
  child: Container(
    height: kToolbarHeight,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: myTable(),
  ),
),
```

Option 2 rendering:

[image]

If you like to have the border, you can wrap your `Table` with `Padding`

```dart
title: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
  child: myTable(),
),
```

Comment: @Noor seems like you've missed on Option 2, feel free to update image +type `Option 1->2`

Comment: I've modified it, but it was not what I was looking for, it doesn't full the full width and height

Comment: Try update answer

Comment: Glad to help, you can also  [implements PreferredSizeWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69056129/10157127)